# Tomcat ha-jdbc cant connect

Tags: tomcat

Who can help with ha-jdbc connection in tomcat7? Need connect to db with jdbc driver.
    Ha-Jdbc jar file was downloaded from web, and placed to the lib location. 
    I've create file (ha-jdbc-mycluster.xml in /etc/tomcat/)
    (The brackets i've removed in this topic)

```
ha-jdbc xmlns="urn:ha-jdbc:cluster:3.0.3"     
cluster    
database id="db1" location="jdbc:sybase:Tds:192.168.10.13:2635?ServiceName=iq_test"    
useruser/user    
passworduserpass/password    
/database    
/cluster    
/ha-jdbc    

Then in context.xml i paste     
    Resource name="jdbc/mycluster"    
type="javax.sql.DataSource"    
factory="net.sf.hajdbc.sql.DataSourceFactory"    
closeMethod="stop"    
cluster="mycluster" config="file:///etc/tomcat/ha-jdbc-mycluster.xml"/
```

When i'm open in probe, the DataSource, i see this message (There are no data sources configured for this Tomcat instance)
    In catalina.out all ok, in the probe.log after refresh page messages 
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.hajdbc.sql.DataSourceFactory
    Maybe my configuration is wrong or what? Thanks

Comment: Where did ypu place the jar, tomcat/lib or webapps/your_webapp/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: I placed it into the tomcat/lib/